# How to get checked table rows to array

Tags: jquery, foreach, html-table

Hi im trying to get the checked rows of my table's second column to an array and pass it to controller parameter.

I have checkboxes and all checked rows will be submitted to the controller parameter. The column i need is named "Index", the values are integers.

My problem is that the  code below alerts blank.

```js
<script>
    var list = [];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').click(function (event) {
            var urls = [];

            $('.table tr').each(function () {
                if ($('.table tr').is(':checked')) {
                    urls.push($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());

                }
                    
                });

                alert(urls);

            });
        
    });
</script>
```

```html
 @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>  
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked" class="idRow"></td>          
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Index)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Adult)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Children)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategorySubName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomId)</td> 
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationStatusName)</td>      
                </tr>
```

What is the solution , thanks

Comment: `$(this).find('.idRow:checkbox').is(':checked')`

Comment: You can't check a table row, you can only check a checkbox or radio button.

Answer (score 0):

`:checked` can't be used as `tr` element. You need check the checkbox in current `tr` element context i.e. `this` can be used in `.each()`.

```
if($(this).find('.idRow:checkbox').is(':checked')){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you're checking if the `tr` is checked - which can never be true. You need to inspect the checkbox within the `tr`. Also note that you should use the `this` keyword within the `each()` handler to only check the element in the current iteration. Try this:

```
var urls = [];
$('.table tr').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.idRow').is(':checked')) {
        urls.push($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
    }
});
```

Note though, that you can improve your logic by using the `map()` method to create the array you need. Try this:

```
var urls = $('.table tr .idRow:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't check a row, you can only check checkboxes and radio buttons. So you need to use `:checked` on the checkbox in the row.

You can get these directly using a selector, you don't need to use `.each()`. Then you can use `.map()` to make an array of the text from the next `<td>`.

```
var urls = $('.table .idRow:checked').parent().next().map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```